# Discover owner of Twitter app via consumer_key and consumer_secret

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have inherited a legacy web application that contains API credentials for a Twitter application.

I have the consumer_key and the consumer_secret.

How do I determine the actual account owner of the application?

Is there a way to regenerate the API credentials without knowing the actual account information (i.e. username/password)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email api@twitter.com. They should be able to reach out to the original developer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: The API team was willing to contact the developer on my behalf.  A portion of the response I received from the API team is: "Unfortunately there is no way to discover information via the API regarding an application with only an API Key. Unfortunately do to our privacy policy we also may not be able to provide any information regarding this application's current registrant"

Comment: @Nathan are you able to find a way to find `username` of the account with the only information like `consumer key` and `consumer secret key`?

Comment: @ZeeshanAfzalSatti No, I was unable to find a way to do this, and I don't recall Twitter support being able to put me in contact either.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can get some additional information if you have an *Access Token* for the app, even if it has expired.

When you create a new app in https://apps.twitter.com you get:

- *Consumer Key (API Key)*
- *Consumer Secret (API Secret)*

If you want to use it, you have to create a *Access Token*, and the results will be two values:

- *Access Token*
- *Access Token Secret*

The page for the app under https://apps.twitter.com will show you the fields "*Owner*" and "*Owner ID*" for the app.

If you have an *Access Token* value --you should have one if you are using the app--, you'll find something like:

'access_token' => '12345678-XxxXXxxXxxXxX1XXXXxx2xXXxXxXXX3xXXxxxxxXX'

The value at the beginning of that value, just before the hyphen (that is, *12345678* in that example) will be the *Owner ID* of the user that created the *Access Token* (you'll have to use your actual value, instead of the 12345678 of the example).

If you go to

https://tweeterid.com/

and enter the *Owner ID* extracted from Access Token field (that will be the same of the app, for example: 20749410), you'll obtain the *Owner* (@finkd = Mark Zuckerberg in this case).

If you are lucky, and the user that create the *Access Token* is the same that created the app, you'll have the answer to your question. It they aren't the same person, at least you can get a minor clue to follow investigating.